# How to communicate between two aspx pages using js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, modalpopupextender

I have two aspx pages namely one.aspx and two.aspx and i have a javascript file named link.js

Now i need to communicate between this two aspx pages using javascript file as intermediate.

In one.aspx file i am having an ModalPopupExtender and the content of its panel is loacted in two.aspx
i.e., in "one.aspx" :

```
<html>
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="link.js"></script>

<script type="type="text/javascript">
   function test(){
     var str=callPopup();
     document.getElementById('pnlPopUp').innerHtml = str;
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="popup1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnOK" CancelControlID="btnCancel" PopupControlID="pnlPopUp"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopUp" runat="server"></asp:Panel>

  </body> 
</html>
```

in "two.aspx" :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="link.js"></script>
   </head>
  <body>
<asp:Panel ID="pPanel1" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>test</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="BtnTest" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClientClick="javascript:alert('hello world..!'); return false;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel> </body> </html>
```

in link.js:

```
function callPopup() {
    var s = document.getElementById('pPanel1').innerHtml;
    return s;
}
```

i am able to call callPopup() from one.aspx but unable to get the content from two.aspx page.
please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more information. You want to do this via a post back or via Ajax? Are you using MVC or WebForms? More information is required. In what context do page 1 and 2 reside? What is the purpose of what you're trying to achieve? What have you tried already?

Comment: hi.. i have edited my question, please review it now..

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you 2 ways to accomplish this.

1. Use SignalR to broadcast to multiple clients.  Read more at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR
2. (more low level.  SignalR usually takes care of all of this for you)

Try using Ajax to call a function server side: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp.
You can then have the function that is called server side write to some output source; Some examples: file, session, cookie.

Then have the other web page constantly reading from that same output (the file, session or cookie) source via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your architecture is correct? 
Is there really a good reason why you need two.aspx - can't one.aspx do it all?

Having used the AjaxToolkit in the past, I struggle to think of a good reason to use it in modern web development. Have you looked at http://knockoutjs.com/ or [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/)? They are really worth a look.

I know this doesn't answer your question *per se*, I'm just trying to save you from a world of pain.

Comment: hi.. the reason behind using two aspx page is, if i place n number of popups(for e.g, 20 to 40) in one aspx, it will take more time to load....